# sd card not found in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-sdcard

my app downloads data from web using jsoup lib. while downloading its shows not such file or directory found. i made sd card manually using CMD. but still m getting error. dont know how to fix this issue.

> **thread code**

```
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Edit.this);
            progressDialog.show();
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                    new WebCopier.Copier( url, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/OfflineBrowser/" + title,
                            maxDepth, bDownloadImages, bDownloadAudio, bDownloadVideo).run();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        fn_ShowMsg("Error 1:" +e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
```

> **copier code**

```
 public static void save ( String filename, String url ) throws Exception
{
    org.jsoup.Connection conn = Jsoup.connect( url );
    conn.timeout( 60000 );
    conn.userAgent( "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.5; en-us; HTC Vision Build/GRI40) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1" );
    conn.ignoreContentType( true );
    byte[] data = conn.execute().bodyAsBytes();
    save( filename, data );
}

public static void save ( String filename, byte[] data ) throws Exception
{
    print( "Saving file %s", filename );
    if (filename.startsWith("file://")){
        URL url = new URL(filename);
        filename = url.getPath();
    }

    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    os.write( data );
    os.close();
}
```

> **Errors**

```
09-23 14:22:{35.377: DEBUG/Output(345): * link <https://play.google.com/store?hl=da> (alternate)
09-23 14:22:38.026: DEBUG/dalvikvm(345): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1549K, 42% free 7714K/13127K, external 929K/1038K, paused 246ms
09-23 14:22:38.115: DEBUG/Output(345): Saving file file:///file:/mnt/sdcard/OfflineBrowser/this /1oujn635h728x/lp1wij6q2wek
09-23 14:22:38.126: WARN/System.err(345): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/mnt/sdcard/OfflineBrowser/this /1oujn635h728x/lp1wij6q2wek (No such file or directory)
09-23 14:22:38.136: WARN/System.err(345): at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
09-23 14:22:38.146: WARN/System.err(345): at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
09-23 14:22:38.146: WARN/System.err(345): at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:94)
09-23 14:22:38.146: WARN/System.err(345): at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
09-23 14:22:38.156: WARN/System.err(345): at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:144)
09-23 14:22:38.156: WARN/System.err(345): at com.example.offlinebrowser.WebCopier.save(WebCopier.java:431)
09-23 14:22:38.156: WARN/System.err(345): at com.example.offlinebrowser.WebCopier.save(WebCopier.java:420)
09-23 14:22:38.167: WARN/System.err(345): at com.example.offlinebrowser.WebCopier$Copier.run(WebCopier.java:178)
09-23 14:22:38.176: WARN/System.err(345): at com.example.offlinebrowser.WebCopier$Copier.run(WebCopier.java:232)
09-23 14:22:38.176: WARN/System.err(345): at com.example.offlinebrowser.Edit$2$1.run(Edit.java:75)
09-23 14:22:38.186: WARN/System.err(345): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Hope somebody can help me please..

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the directory you are using is already created..

```
if (filename.startsWith("file://")){
    URL url = new URL(filename);
    filename = url.getPath();
    File dir = new File(filename);
    if (!dir.exists()) // not exist? make it!
        dir.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: still showing same errors, if you need more info related copier code then i can show you.... @Nermeen

Comment: are you sure that the path is correct, there is a space after (this) (/file:/mnt/sdcard/OfflineBrowser/this /1oujn635h728x/lp1wij6q2wek (No such file or directory))

Comment: their is no mistake. look at this.
09-23 15:59:58.406: DEBUG/Output(426): * script: <https://wallet.google.com/inapp/lib/buy.js>
09-23 16:00:00.949: DEBUG/Output(426): Saving file file:///file:/mnt/sdcard/OfflineBrowser/tit /hs29y05gei32/7mfm99n7it75.js
09-23 16:00:00.956: WARN/System.err(426): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/mnt/sdcard/OfflineBrowser/tit /hs29y05gei32/7mfm99n7it75.js (No such file or directory)
09-23 16:00:00.967: WARN/System.err(426): at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)

Comment: i can see a space after (tit) and before (/) in (tit /hs29y05gei32)

Comment: oh,there is a space. how to solv this? thanks for the help,in advance.

Comment: what is the value of the variable title in (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/OfflineBrowser/" + title)

Comment: its a string type, used for folder name in which all the downloaded data will save..